# Determine the type of Object to use to store a Linq Query

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

I am using VB .Net for this, so I don't have access to `var` or this would be a simple matter.

Right now my query is as follows

```
Dim errors As IOrderedQueryable(Of IGrouping(Of String, RSError)) = (From e In db.RSErrors 
                                                                     Where e.UserID = "msarchet" 
                                                                     Group e By e.Type Into t = Group).AsEnumerable
```

So I used this query in LinqPad to help me determine what the object would look like. I got back a `IOrderQueryable(Of RSError)` which then contained a `IGrouping(Of String, RSError)` for each grouped collection of objects returned by the query.

However I ended up with the current object type of `errors` as `IOrderedQueryable(Of IGrouping(Of String, RSError))` because of the cast error I am getting in VS.

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1[VB$AnonymousType_1`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[RSSAdmin2.RSError]]]' to type 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.String,RSSAdmin2.RSError]]'.`

I'm not sure how to get rid of the VB$AnonymousType_1 Part of the returned object.

Am I even on the right track here or am I missing something completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following

```
Dim errors = (From e In db.RSErrors 
              Where e.UserID = "msarchet" 
              Group e By e.Type Into t = Group).AsEnumerable
```

Doing it this way basically sets it to

> Dim errors As <strike>Object</strike> [Whatever the expression returns]

Comment: I could do it Implicitly...sigh this is what I get for working under conditions that require Explicit declaration all the time.

Comment: yes I understand what the implicit declaration does, and it works, thank you for jump starting my saturday brain

Comment: No, it won't create the type `Object`. This changed in VB9 and it will actually create the specific type that the expression returns, just like the `var` keyword in C# 3.